# Работа с буфером обмена

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, стоит такая, не разрешимая мною задача: нужно скопировать любой выделенный текст (может быть текст из блокнота, ворда, названия файла) в буфер обмена, а затем вывести его на экран консоли. Подскажите, какими функциями реализуется всё это?

Спасибо.

Comment: А в какой системе?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например так:

```
if( OpenClipboard(NULL) )
{
    char* data = (char*)GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
            if(data)
               ;//делай что хочешь с данными, например - выводи на консоль
            CloseClipboard();

    }
```

Если же надо не просто вывести что УЖЕ скопировано, а найти окно эдита (вообще то в ворде уже и не эдит наверно) и взять текст оттуда, то это задача сложнее, но тоже вполне разрешимая. Можешь юзать FindWindow и FindWindowEx и снять текст с помощью GetWindowText, но тогда копировать в буфер и не обязательно, можешь прямо оттуда в консоль

Comment: Колоссально, никогда не думал, что так просто. Все скомпилировалось (Copy/Paste (почти)) влет и напечатало свой текст !!!